# PInvoke errors after a WinCE5 device returns from Standby mode?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I'm developing on a Windows CE 5 device that has a printer. I've got a running VB.Net (compact) program on it and no problems interacting with the device's Printer library there. But with a program written in C#, I got PInvoke errors after the device had been in standby mode for a while. I managed to fix that problem by copying the .dll file from the device's Windows folder and pasting it in the C# program's directory.

Now, I'm getting problems with the SQL Server CE DLL! Same thing -- it's happening on the C#, but not the VB.Net program, and it happens after the device had been in standby mode for a long while. It doesn't happen with all components of SQL Server CE either - just when I'm doing a merge replication. To get it to work again I close and re-run the program. And that's fine for me but not acceptable for users.

What could be causing this? Is it just a difference with C#? I don't want to have to paste all SQL Server CE libraries in my program directory.

(Both programs have the SQL Server CE library added to References, both have `using/Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe` in the code)

Answer (score 1):

You should make your device Suspend/Resume aware. Note that the suspend notification is delivered AFTER the next resume.

Most programmers forget that a Mobile device is not in an always connected and powered state. If the device suspends, for example, and the app has opened a file on external storage. the storage might be powered down/up during a suspend/resume cycle. The app then needs to close the file and re-open it. Same with network and other wireless or wired connections. These may go down during suspend and need to be re-initialized on resume.

Comment: For this reason it would be good if Yves could tell in which part of the software the exception is raised. Maybe it is a database on a network-store.